# Why is this interrupt handler causing a general protection fault? (Solved)

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, interrupt, interrupt-handling

```
interrupt_handler:

    ; stores the address and segment of the instruction that caused a fault
    ; if this interrupt is not a fault, the variables will contain garbage
    ; but the C++ knows when to ignore them
    push eax
    mov eax, [esp + 4]
    mov dword [fault_address], eax
    mov ax, [esp + 8]
    mov word [fault_segment], ax
    pop eax

    pusha

    push dword [int_number]
    call InterruptCallback
    add esp, 4

    popa ; <- I have determined that this line causes the GPF (using the debug code I wrote)

global IgnoreInterrupt
IgnoreInterrupt:

    iret



section .data

int_number dd 0

global interrupt_error
interrupt_error dd 0

global fault_address
fault_address dd 0

global fault_segment
fault_segment dw 0
```

Here is the C++ 'InterruptCallback' function.

```
extern "C" void InterruptCallback(uint8_t interrupt) {
    printf("INTERRUPT ");
    
    
    if (interrupt == GP_FAULT) {
        printLong(fault_address);
    }
}
```

I am testing this using this driving function:

```
; void EnableInterrupts()
EnableInterrupts:
    int 0
    ;sti
    ret
```

As you can see, I had previously enabled interrupts and was getting the same behavior as when I call 'int 0'. If I had to guess what is causing it, I would say the stack pointer is somehow getting misaligned and causing an invalid segment selector to be loaded into a segment register, but I don't see how this code is misaligning the stack pointer. I am new to assembly so I may be missing something obvious. Let me know if there is any other code you need to see (Ex, how the interrupt descriptor table and global descriptor table are set up), however, I am fairly confident they were created correctly.

Solution: For reasons that will remain unknown to me, adding an empty segment descriptor after the null descriptor in my Global Descriptor table fixed this.

Comment: The `popa` is unlikely to be the fault if the preceding code worked. You probably debugged wrong. Your handler doesn't look very robust as it does not set the environment to known good values but it should suffice for your test case I guess.

Comment: I wrote down the fault address that was printed and used a dissassembler to find the instruction at that address, it was the popa. What do you mean by setting the environment to known good values?

Comment: I don't see how the `popa` can fault if the `pusha` worked and the compiler didn't mess up the stack in your `InterruptCallback` function. I assume the page is present and executable. It's possible but unlikely that execution ended up at that address in other ways but my bet is on wrong debugging.

Comment: Som exceptions have an error code placed on the stack below the return address that need to be removed before doing an `iret`. #GP exception is one with an error code: https://wiki.osdev.org/Exceptions. YOur solution doesn't sound like a solution but is hiding some underlying issue. If you should us all your assembly and C code it would help. If you remove the print functions and the problem still exists you can leave that code out and reduce the code to a smaller [mcve]. My concern is you have a bug and you are shifting it around by adding an extra entry in the GDT.